# Json object getting unecessary elements?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am getting this kind of json output  :

```
{"OrderSummary":"[
        {\"ProductQuantity\":\"1\",
        \"ProductName\":\"Wine\",
        \"Sellerid\":\"2\",
        \"ProductCost\":\"500\"}
        ,

       {\"ProductQuantity\":\"1\",
       \"ProductName\":\"Whisky\",
        \"Sellerid\":\"1\",
       \"ProductCost\":\"500\"
       }
   ]"
}
```

And i want this kind of output

```
{"Order Summary":
    [

      {
         "ProductQuantity":"1",
         "ProductName":"Wine",
         "Sellerid":"2",
         "ProductPrice":"500",
         "ProductCost":"500"     
      },
      {
        "ProductQuantity":"1",
        "ProductName":"Whisky",
        "Sellerid":"2",
        "ProductPrice":"200",
        "ProductCost":"200"
      }
    ]}
```

and this is my code while obtaining the json array and json object

```
 Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getCarProducts();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            JSONObject product = new JSONObject();
            try {
                product.put("Sellerid",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Sellerid")));
                product.put("ProductCost",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Cost")));
                product.put("ProductQuantity",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Quantity")));
                product.put("ProductPrice",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Price")));
                product.put("ProductName",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_Name")));
                userCart.put(product);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
             Cart = new JSONObject();
          try
          {
              Cart.put("OrderSummary",userCart.toString());
          }
          catch (Exception ex){ }
```

Can anybody tell me where iam going wrong?

iam have not seen this kind of output and iam unable to discover the cause for it ?

Comment: That looks to me like the string representation of the json you want.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after one week of searching, banging head,testing and trying different codes i finally found the answer to the problem and the cause of the problem

**The Cause:**
to avoid extra ""(inverted commas) the json system puts these kind of forward slashes .
**The solution :**
to avoid getting error due to these forward slashes we  can use stripslashes() function provided by the php(from version 5.4)

the follwing php code could really help in order to convert the json result produced :-

```
$jsonstring={"Order Summary":
[ 
   {
     \ "ProductName\":\"Wine\",
      \"ProductPrice\":\"500\",
      \"ProductQuantity\":\"2\",
      \"ProductCost\":\"1000\",
      \"SellerId\":\"2\"

   },
   {
      \"ProductName\":\"Whiskey\",
      \"ProductPrice\":\"1000\",
      \"ProductQuantity\":\"1\",
      \"ProductCost\":\"1000\",
      \"SellerId\":\"1\"

   }
]}
$jsondata=json_decode(stripslashes($jsonstring),true);
print_r($jsondata);
```